# Making a DB on a remote server

Tags: database

I need to make a database on a remote server, and since I have been using [craftman](https://github.com/gabrielmoreira/craftman) installer which uses Docker to install Craft CMS and DB locally I have no idea how does the DB actually looks like. How can I check and see what is DB like, and export the sql file so that I can import it on the remote server?
I have tried to connect to it using these settings:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: root
Password: 
Database: craft
Port: 3306
```

I have also tried with changing the Db name from craft to the name of my project, but that didn't work either, not sure where I can find the right settings and how to connect to DB?

Answer (score 1):

Never used craftman before, but it [looks like](https://github.com/gabrielmoreira/craftman/blob/master/craftman#L99) the database name it creates is called `craft` and it's pulling the database [user and password](https://github.com/gabrielmoreira/craftman/blob/master/craftman#L504-L505) from some environment variables named `CRAFT_DB_USER` and `CRAFT_DB_PASSWORD` you could check for.

Comment: I am trying to connect to a localhost port 3306, db name craft, user root, and from what it seems to me in the craft\app\config\db.php password can be left out, but I can't connect to the db. I have tried with changing the name of the db, from craft to the name of my project and I still couldn't connect to it.